# Should I add the previously learned technologies not in use at current job to my resume

Tags: resume, career-development, technology, india

I have looked at [Should I discard technologies that I don't want to work anymore from my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4422/2598)

But my scenario is little bit different. I am working in a company setup of about 40 to 50 employees. I have been working on **X** technology for the last six months. Here I found that our seniors have shifted their roles over time to meet the company's requirements.

I have studied **Y** technology before, but haven't got much of experience in it, and thus I removed it from my resume (also it was totally different from the **X** technology). Here in this company, demand of **X** technology is rather higher than that of **Y** technology and in the near future, we could expect people to shift to the **X** technology.

No one here knows that I also have a good knowledge of **X** technology. So should I add the **X** technology to my resume considering the future aspect or not?

Also I am thinking of practicing or doing some advance studies on the **X** technology being at my current job. Should I imitate my manager in that I am practicing over the **X** technology?

**Edit** I am from the Indian community and precisely saying from a province of India which is not much developed in terms of technology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are working on and the technologies you are currently using are certainly relevant to your CV and should definitely be on it.

If you are further studying these technologies to improve your knowledge and understanding of them, you should indeed tell your manager about it, as it would make you more relevant to the current fashion in your workplace.

As for the technologies that are *not* used in your current workplace - you need to ask yourself if these are valuable in other places - other potential employers. If the answer is yes, having them on your CV is a good idea. It will not hurt your prospects in your current work place either - it is better to show proficiency in more than one technology, it makes you more valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the process of looking for a new job, or you are in a position where your resume is relevant within your company when you apply for internal jobs or a promotion - then certainly keep it up to date with the skills and technologies you have learned and would be competent to perform, so long as they are useful to someone in your profession or the specific company.  Whether you've used them recently or on this specific job may be something you clarify in each job descrption - not as negative but by explicitly stating what technologies have been most relevant recently.

Keep in mind that in many companies, your resume is not an active part of your employee profile after you join.  As a manager, for example, I rarely consider my employees resumes when assigning day to day.  More important is my perception of their current research, their interest in the technology, and places overall where they would grow and be challenged.  For my team, we schedule one on one time, because our schedules can get crazy, but for other groups this can be more informal - it depends on company culture.  But it's definitely good to say to your manager (and even other team members) - "oh, by the way, I know stuff about this area that seems to need skilled people..." and also have the discussion with your manager about training - training yourself is great, and checking in to see if the manager has any recommendations is even better.